# Unexpected token < on line 2

Tags: apex

I'm trying to fetch records based on a set of records (used in subquery) and I get the above error.

Bwlow is a code snippet of how I've written the query.

```
 Set<String> setContactIds = new Set<String>{'0036A00000u5cho'};
 List<Schedule__c> lstWeeklySchedule = [SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g
                                FROM Schedule__c
                                WHERE ID IN: (SELECT Id                                      
                                               FROM Employees__r                                     
                                               WHERE ID IN:setContactIds)];
    system.debug('lstWeeklySchedule : ' +lstWeeklySchedule);
```

Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax on the join is wrong. You need to use the API Name of the object, which would always end in `__c`. Child or parent relationship names end in `__r`, but those should not be used in any filter joins.

Comment: there is also an extra `:` in that query